# Entity Framework Keeps overwriting attributes. Need other way of solving issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing app / dataabse. I have been tasked to add in Entity Framework as part of an upgrade.

I hit a problem where when I generate (or regenerate) the edmx, the code no longer recognises the foreign keys in the database tables, and when the code runs, it complains about missing id's, as, I assume, it is 'guessing' what the foreign keys should be.

I can get round this by adding the following attribute to the Auto generated model definitions.

```
[ForeignKey("NavigationProperty")]
```

But then, if / when the edmx is regenerated, all this gets blown away, and has to be re-added.

Although the class that is generated is partial, as these attributes are being added to existing members, I cannot move them to a seperate file.

So, how do I get round this option? Ideally I'd like to ensure that when the edmx is generated it picks up the foreign keys, so that this issue is fixed permanently. If that can't be done, next step is to ask if there is some way of programatically generating these associations, so it is only done once.

Thanks

edit - Added in sample table definition

Here is the code auto generated by SMS. Is tehre anything wrong with the foreign key definition?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShopProductTypes](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Shop_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Product_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CancelledDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Archived] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ShopProductTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ShopProductTypes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_ShopProductTypes_Shop] FOREIGN KEY([Shop_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Shops] ([Id])
GO
```

Comment: What is the database backend?

Comment: I think you need to fix the edmx / database - then the generated files will be fine - ie: are the FK's defined in the database? If not you will need to add them to the model

Comment: Thats just it, the fk's are defined in the database. So either they are not defined correctly (if that is possible), or Entiy Framework dislikes their names

Comment: maybe the best bet for this is to abandon entity framework model first, and instead use Code First, so that you avoid the need for a "regeneration".  Personally, I prefer 100% pocos, and I build as part of the DbContext the mapping between the objects and database.  It allows me to interchange NHibernate and Entity Fx if Entity Fx or NHibernate fails dependent on the situation.

Comment: Trouble is, the database is vaery mature, adn this is an attempt to retrofit EF to it / upgrade the app to a more modern state. And whilst I don't know much about EF, Im guessing that code first is not an option for me now.

Comment: @Matt - I assume you're using MSSQL?  Do the relationships show up in the edmx designer as lines between tables?  Or does each table stand entirely alone and unconnected?

Comment: @Bobson, there are lines and arrows between the tables

Comment: @Matt - I think we might need more information.  Can you post the XML (from the edmx) and the generated class for the table you posted?  Maybe in comparing them we can spot something.

Comment: its going to be a huge amount of xml, as it is part of a much larger data set. For now I have gone code first as Richard B suggested, and it is working. Not that great as the db has a lot of tables and joins, but it means I can make progress and keep my customer happy..

Comment: @Matt - If you want to keep looking for a better answer, I'd just want to see the XML for that one table (or the Shop table too).  If you'd rather stick with Code First, that's fine too.

Comment: @Bobson thanks, I'll try and clip it out tomorrow, is it just the table definition you need?

Comment: I think so?  I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for, but since it seems like it's set up right in the database, then there's something else failing and I'm hoping to be able to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2007/09/01/ef-codegen-events-for-fun-and-profit-aka-how-to-add-custom-attributes-to-my-generated-classes.aspx

It's a bit more involved.

Comment: Thanks, but that is somethign else that will need to be run each time the edmx is regenerated, and with the best will in the world, someone will forget it sooner or later. I'll look into it, but I think that really I need to figure out what is wrong in the database..